# Ошибка в коде, как я понял, не открывается нужный файл: RuntimeError: open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen

Tags: python, pip, распознавание-речи

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'ru_v3'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya'  # aidar, kseniya, xenia, random
put_accent = True
put_yo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')

text = "Ты кто?"

model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                          model='silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                          speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yo=put_yo)

print(text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
sd.stop()
```

***Простой код для проигрывания звука через библиотеку sounddevice. И мне выдают такую ошибку:***

```
Using cache found in C:\Users\Администратор/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\PycharmProjects\janet\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 542, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 572, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 87, in silero_tts
    imp = package.PackageImporter(model_path)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\package\package_importer.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.zip_reader = torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(self.filename)
RuntimeError: open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen: No such file or directory, file path: C:\Users\Администратор/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\model\ru_v3.pt
```

[Вот видео откуда взял код, там и объяснение строк](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeGvaDaraI&list=PLoTp09pLNdbezMdmU-RL07fJf5-Mgu1_r&index=13&t=155s)

Comment: файл есть, могу скинуть скрин

Answer (score 0):

Установи модуль silero глобально

```
pip install silero
```